# Unable to select average scores for different locations using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

I am trying to select average scores specific to location for comparison
purposes. Using the statement

```
SELECT l.location_name AS "Location Of Store",
        AVG (f.score) AS "Average Score"
    FROM feedback AS f
    JOIN employee AS e
        ON f.qr_id = e.qr_id
    JOIN location AS l
        ON e.location_id = l.location_id
    WHERE e.company_id = '1'
```

[results in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JHmk.png)

```
+ ----------------- + ------------- +
| Location of Store | Average Score |
+ ----------------- + ------------- +
| London            | 5.3333        |
+ ----------------- + ------------- +
```

If I drop the average

```
SELECT l.location_name AS "Location Of Store",
        f.score AS "Average Score"
    FROM feedback AS f
    JOIN employee AS e
        ON f.qr_id = e.qr_id
    JOIN location AS l
        ON e.location_id = l.location_id
    WHERE e.company_id = '1'
```

[Then the results I want to see however this isn't the average score](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kjr3.png)

```
+ ----------------- + ------------- +
| Location of Store | Average Score |
+ ----------------- + ------------- +
| London            | 9             |
| Bedfordshire      | 2             |
| Buckinghamshire   | 5             |
+ ----------------- + ------------- +
```

Probably missing something simple can't put my finger on it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're just missing a "group by" clause. Also, I don't think your first statement would even compile right?

Try this:

```
SELECT l.location_nameAS "Location Of Store", AVG (f.score) AS "Average Score"
FROM feedbackAS f
JOIN employeeAS e
ON f.qr_id= e.qr_id
JOIN locationAS l
ON e.location_id = l.location_id
WHERE e.company_id = '1'
GROUP BY l.location_name
```

Group by clauses literally group the results of aggregate functions by the values in a different field. An aggregate function is like min, max, count, avg, stddev, etc.

Comment: Bang on the money can't believe I missed it, spent too long looking at this screen today. The top statement found the average of all the results as shown in the picture of 5.5.